Flutter Android Simulator Fails to Run with Audio Package
I’m encountering an issue when trying to run my Flutter application on the Android simulator that uses an audio package. Despite attempting various audio packages, I continue to face build failures. Here are the details of my setup and the error message I'm receiving:
Environment:
Flutter Version: 3.24.3
Dart Version: 3.5.3
Android SDK Version: 34.0.0
Android Studio Version: 2024.2
Java Version: OpenJDK 21.0.3


Steps Taken:
I've tried various audio packages (like audioplayers and assets_audio_player) but encountered the same issue.
I verified my Android SDK installation and updated to the latest version.
Request for Help:
Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to resolve this? Any guidance on troubleshooting this Gradle task failure would be greatly appreciated!
